# Поиск имен в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Какие определения должны использоваться в шаблонном классе, в случае, если возникает неоднозначность между именем шаблонного параметра и типом, определенном в базовом классе зависимом от шаблонного параметра?

MSVC и G++ ведут себя по разному. Кто прав и почему?

Пример: https://godbolt.org/z/1Efa9zvEs

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S1
{};

struct S2 : S1
{
    using Base=S1;
};

template<typename Base>
struct Wrap : Base
{
    using base=Base;
};

static_assert( std::is_same_v< Wrap<S2>::base, S2 > ); // g++ - ok, msvc - fail
static_assert( std::is_same_v< Wrap<S2>::base, S1 > ); // msvc - ok, g++ - fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В определении:

```
template<typename Base>
struct Wrap : Base
{
    using base = Base;
};
```

шаблонный параметр `Base` вводит имя `Base` в пространство имен класса `Wrap`. Соответственно, когда мы объявляем type alias:

```
using base = Base;
```

, `Base` не может быть ничем иным, как типом, которым параметризуется `Wrap` при инстанцировании. И раз мы инстанцируем его с `S2`, то `Base` - это `S2`.

C моей точки зрения прав g++.

---

UPD.: в более свежей версии компилятора MSVC static_assert [фэйлится](https://godbolt.org/z/oasWjb9jE).